# `WP_REST_Controller::get_endpoint_args_for_item_schema` Does Not Set `required` Property from Schema

Tags: rest-api

I need help with Schemas and my `WP_REST_Controller`.

I've extended `WP_REST_Controller` to create a custom rest endpoint for a plugin. I've added a schema for the endpoint. The Schema is visible in an OPTIONS request, and validation by the Argument Schema for a POST seems to be working like magic automatically.

**But `get_endpoint_args_for_item_schema()` from the base WP_REST_Controller class always sets `required: false`, even when the schema defines `'required' => true`.**

I'd like for Wordpress to also validate whether a Request body argument is missing.

Can anyone explain this? What have I misconfigured? OPTIONS Request to this endpoint returns the following Response.

```php
final class Custom_Route_REST_Controller extends WP_REST_Controller {
    register_rest_route($namespace, '/' . $base, [
        [
            'methods'             => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
            'callback'            => [$this, 'get_items'],
            'permission_callback' => [$this, 'get_items_permissions_check'],
            'args'                => [],
        ],
        [
            'methods'             => WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
            'callback'            => [$this, 'create_item'],
            'permission_callback' => [$this, 'create_item_permissions_check'],
            'args'                => $this->get_endpoint_args_for_item_schema(true),
        ],
        'schema' => [$this, 'get_item_schema'],
    ]);
    public function get_item_schema()
    {
        return [
            '$schema'              => 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#',
            'type'                 => 'object',
            'properties'           => [
                'name'  => [
                    'type'     => 'string',
                    'description'  => esc_html__("The human name for the item.", 'text-domain'),
                    'context'      => ['view', 'edit'],
                    'required' => true,
                ],
        ];
    }
}
```

```json
{
    "methods": [
        "GET",
        "POST"
    ],
    "endpoints": [
        {
            "methods": [
                "GET"
            ],
            "args": []
        },
        {
            "methods": [
                "POST"
            ],
            "args": {
                "name": {
                    "description": "The human name for the item.",
                    "type": "string",
                    "required": false // ⬅️ This IS NOT set like I want
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "schema": {
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
        "title": "course",
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
            "name",
            "institution_id"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "The human name for the item.",
                "context": [
                    "view",
                    "edit"
                ],
                "required": true // ⬅️ This IS set like I want
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`WP_REST_Controller::get_endpoint_args_for_item_schema()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_controller/get_endpoint_args_for_item_schema/) takes a single argument as the method for which to retrieve argument definitions for. It's underlying mechanism - the [`rest_get_endpoint_args_for_schema()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_get_endpoint_args_for_schema/) - only processes `required` attributes in the case of the `CREATABLE` methods.

Change

```php
$this->get_endpoint_args_for_item_schema(true)
```

to specify the method, i.e.

```php
$this->get_endpoint_args_for_item_schema( WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE )
```

or simply omit the argument and it will default to that value.

Comment: Genius! I got the non-working code from the Wordpress docs. It is from the "starter custom Route". Do you know a way to update those docs? I'd like to help other avoid putting the wrong argument! https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#examples

Comment: Nice quick catch on WordPress's deviation from JSON Schema spec! I really appreciate your desire to contribute as well :) . You'll want to get in touch with the [Make Documentation](https://make.wordpress.org/docs/) team on Slack or file an issue on the [Documentation Issue Tracker](https://github.com/WordPress/Documentation-Issue-Tracker). I'm not entirely sure what their workflow is, but there's probably a means for more direct contribution

Comment: Thanks! And just checking, `get_endpoint_args_for_item_schema(true)` is just wrong?

Comment: Correct, yeah - even as far back as [the original implementation](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.7-branch/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-controller.php#L522) of that function, I can't find any evidence that the method has ever done anything with a boolean argument